# IndexedDB callbacks don't fire if breakpoints trigger on their assignment

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, event-loop

Check this snippet:

```
function connect() {
    var request = window.indexedDB.open('test', 1);

    request.onerror = function(event) {
      console.log('error');
    };

    request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
      console.log('upgrade needed');
    };

    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
      console.log('success');
    };
}

connect();
```

When I put breakpoints on callbacks assignment lines (4, 8, 12) and run it in chrome debugger, the code inside callbacks will never fire. Contrary, this code will work correctly:

```
  function connect2() {
    var IDB = {
      open: function() {
        var req = {};
        setTimeout(() => {
          req.onsuccess();
        }, 0)
        return req;
      }
    }
    var request = IDB.open();

    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
        console.log('onsuccess2');
    };
  }
  connect2();
```

Do I understand correctly, that the case with IndexedDB.open and debugger breaks js event loop? What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me! onsuccess and onupgradeneeded are called!
See fiddle:

```js
function connect() {
    var request = window.indexedDB.open('test', 1);

    request.onerror = function(event) {
      console.log('error');
    };

    request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
      console.log('upgrade needed');
    };

    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
      console.log('success');
    };
}

connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use more modular:

```js
var APP = APP || {};

APP.Database = (function(){
 
  return {
      request : null,

      init : function()
      {
          this.connect();
          this.request.onerror = this.logError;
          this.request.onupgradeneeded = this.onUpgradedNeeded;
          this.request.onsuccess = this.onSuccessCallback;
      },
      connect : function()
      {
        this.request = window.indexedDB.open('test', 1);
      },
      onSuccessCallback : function(evt)
      {
        console.log('Successfully conneted!');
      },
      logError : function(evt)
      {
        console.log('error');
      },
      onUpgradedNeeded : function(evt)
      {
         console.log('upgrade needed');
      }
    };  
})();


APP.Database.init();
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a useful code, i'll keep it. But the problem is about execution order.